# Redefine this C++ variable

Tags: c++

This variable keeps saying it's undefined, which is fine. But how do I redefine it?

I need to redefine this variable.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string b1 = "undefined";
    cout << "Schedule\n";
    string p1;
    cin >> p1;
    if (p1 == "1") {
        string b1 = "ELA";
    } else if (p1 == "7/8") {
        string b1a = "SCIENCE";
    } else {
        string b1 = "404/undefined\n";
    }

    cout << "Results:\n\n";
    cout << b1;
}
```

Comment: Please use workplace-appropriate language on Stack Overflow, not language which may be offensive to some groups of people. Please see: [Are expletives (cursing, swear words, vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites) Keep in mind that using offensive language tends to result in people reacting poorly to your posts (i.e. they may downvote). In addition, do you really want a future employer to see you using such language in a situation which is intended to be professional?

Comment: Don't redeclare/redefine it: `string b1 = "ELA";` → `b1 = "ELA";`, etc.

Comment: `string b1 = "ELA";` this variable is only visible in the surrounding blocks scope. You have to define it outside, and only assign the values in the `fi() {} else {}` blocks.

Comment: *"Fix it. Please."* -- I was uncertain as to what "it" referred, so I chose to interpret it as referring to your question (but I only fixed some cosmetic parts -- adding details and clarity, such as identifying which variable, is still on you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot redefine variable, that's simply not possible in C++.

Good news is, you don't need to. As the name "variable" suggests, you can change it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string b1 = "undefined";
    cout << "Schedule\n";
    string p1;
    cin >> p1;
    if (p1 == "1") {
        b1 = "ELA"; //don't redeclare, reassign
    } else if (p1 == "7/8") {
        b1 = "SCIENCE";
    } else {
        b1 = "404/undefined\n";
    }

    cout << "Results:\n\n";
    cout << b1;
}
```